# System of recurrence relations with unknown delay

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I was wondering if there is any way to solve this system of recurrences (initial conditions $X_0$, $Y_0$ and $Z_0$ are known):

\begin{align*}
X_t &= a_1 X_{t-1}+a_2 X_{t-a} + a_3 Y_{t-a} + a_4 Y_t \\
Y_t &= b_1 Y_{t-1} + b_2 X_t \\
Z_t &= c_1 Z_{t-1} + c_2 Y_t
\end{align*}

Here we have $a\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_i, b_j, c_k \in\mathbb{R}$.

The problem is, I've tried using the second equation and plugging it into the first one, trying to get the first recurrence to be only in $X$, but the problem is that $a$ is unknown and the recurrence becomes very complicated.

I couldn't find any helpful literature on the subject of systems of recurrences except hints that I should first try to express one recurrence in terms of just one variable so that I get a linear recurrence.